# How to modify static resources inside folders?

Tags: static-resources

We were able to deploy static resources inside folders from a sandbox, by using IlluminatedCloud as an IDE: we copied/pasted a folder inside staticresources and we placed some files inside it, and it all worked.

However, when we want to edit the static resources in production, we only see the folders and not the files inside the folders.   Is there a way through the user interface to modify the resources inside folders?

Answer (score 5):

Through the Salesforce user interface? No. You either need to deploy from Illuminated Cloud to production, or make the modifications locally, zip up the resource file, and upload that to Salesforce through the UI.

Comment: Some other IDEs do this for you automatically as well, for example, Cloud9. Of course, the Force.com IDE does *not* do it for you automatically, but that's what you get for a free tool.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that IlluminatedCloud is automatically zipping the folder content into the single static resource per folder.

If you download a zipped static resource from production via the Setup UI and save it on your local machine, you can manually unzip it, modify the content and then re-zip it. (Double check that you have not accidentally introduced another level of folder inside the static resource.) You can then re-upload the resulting file.

(But not sure for production if the static resources can be updated this way.)

Comment: So the folders are actually zip files?

Comment: @Edmondo1984 A static resource can only be either a file or a zip file and only the latter allows multiple items in one static resource (and can include internal folders). Check the IlluminatedCould documentation, but yes I think IlluminatedCloud is automatically converting the folder content to a zip file on the fly as the depoloyment is done.

Comment: Yes, Static Resources that have multiple files inside them are zip archives: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pages_static_resources.htm&type=5